# livewire after the search the text trimming script does not work "...see more"

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

[after search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyHZM.png)

I am using a script to trim part of the post
and button "..see more".
on first page load, everything works fine,
but after searching almost all posts are deployed the script doesn't work.
can someone help me?

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('.desc').shorten({
     chars: 300,
     ellipses: '...',
     more: 'see more',
     less: '...less'
  });
});
```

```
public function render(){
  return view('livewire.search-posts', [
    'posts' => JobPost::where('title', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orderBy('published_at','desc')
            ->paginate($this->perPage),]);
}
```

```
<div class="post-container  pl-0 mr-2 desc" wire:ignore >
  {!! $post->text !!}
</div>
```

sorry for my English

Comment: please clarify this line, *but after searching almost all posts are deployed the script doesn't work*

Comment: @STA when I clear the search bar to reset the filter, the '...see more' button disappears and the posts are not cropped, look at the image I attached.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, this is probably happening because your jquery script is not being loaded in your component since livewire refreshes the component after every request

there are two possible solutions

1. make sure your component view has one root div

   ```
     <div>
        <div class="post-container  pl-0 mr-2 desc" wire:ignore >
           {!! $post->text !!}
        </div>
     </div>
   ```
2. remove the `wire:ignore` and by updating your code like below

   add this at the bottom of your component view

   ```
   @push('scripts')
       <script>
           document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
               window.livewire.hook('afterDomUpdate', () => {
                   jQuery(function($) {
                       $('.desc').shorten({
                          chars: 300,
                          ellipses: '...',
                          more: 'see more',
                          less: '...less'
                       });
                   });
              });
          });
      </script>
   ```

   @endpush

   put the stack blad tag in your layout file just above the body closing tag

   ```
           @stack('scripts')
      </body>
   ```

   every time the component is refreshed/updated this will make sure your script is
   also included